# How to label individual tiles in a Tilegram hex map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building something like this, but each tile would have distinct info, not just each state. (I.e., each tile corresponds to a different district within each state). Is there a way to append data to individual tiles in D3 in order to have an info box or popup for each one?

https://pitchinteractiveinc.github.io/tilegrams/

Comment: Please provide a code snippet or fiddle with some data